# So I am learning how to do Fourier series expansion

Tags: fourier-series

So I am learning how to do Fourier series expansions by writing the function expression from given graphs:

To find the series, we calculate A0,An and Bn and plug those values in the main Fourier series formula and get a few trigonometric components expansions.
However, the problem I am facing is both my An and Bn come to 0 after doing the integration which is unusual.
I have written the function below with the limits I am using in the math and also attached a photo of the figure.
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0&, -2<x<1 \\
      5&, -1<x<1 \\
      0&,  1<x<2 \\
\end{cases}
$$
I would really appreciate it if anyone solve this math/tell me what am I doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: The photo is missing. Also, please write the formulas using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The function is even, so I'd expect that the $B_n=0$. If you edit to show what your definition of $A_n$ actually is then it would be possible to help.

Comment: Thanks for the hint